# How do i get the Header Body in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-http

How do I access the `HEADERS` data in Angular 2?

My NGINX server sends the `HEADERS` object you see below. I have used Express so far and I could get the data very easily, but I have been trying to do so on Angular 2 with no luck. My app requires the header body to perform other operations.

**NOTE** User -> Nginx ( Sends Header ) -> Angular2 ?!?! how to read it

```
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {"server":"nginx","date":"Thu, 02 Mar 2017 06:31:17 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","transfer-encoding":"chunked","connection":"close","vary":"Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding",.... and so on

BODY: {"other stuf .... "}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/voliva/angular2-interceptors) it adds the **interceptor** feature to Angular 2, by extending the **@angular/http** class.

Although you can write your own class extending the http class but that would take time and since angular2 doesn not provide any intercepting capabilities you are better off this library.

Comment: Thats the thing , im sending the Header Body from NGINX to Angular2 ... i need to intercept it on Angular not to make a Request from Angular to something else .

Comment: by the way you can check the header info  from networks tab in developer console in chrome